# Convert multiple timezones in a variable using 'lubridate'

Tags: r, timezone, lubridate

### Data

I have a vector of times, each in different timezones e.g

```r
x = c("2024-01-05 11:12:13 UTC", "2024-01-10 12:13:14 CET", "2024-01-15 07:08:09 EST")
```

### Question

How can I get info about the timezone for each element and use it to convert these data into one "universal" timezone, e.g. "UTC"?
Solutions using `{base}` or `{lubridate}` are preferred.

### Attempt

```r
dtf <- 
  tibble(
    x <- c("2024-01-05 11:12:13 UTC", "2024-01-10 12:13:14 CET", "2024-01-15 07:08:09 EST")
    y <- str_extract(x, "[^ ]+$")
  )
dtf %>% 
  map(
   y, ~ as_datetime(x, tz = y)
  )
```

which gives `NULL` values.

Comment: Hi, Karol! It would be nice if you could respond. Otherwise we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

This, hopefully, serves as an R base approach getting you started.

```
x = c("2024-01-05 11:12:13 UTC", "2024-01-10 12:13:14 CET", "2024-01-15 07:08:09 EST")
Y = data.frame(t(list2DF(strsplit(x,"\\s+(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)))) |> 
  setNames(c("tmp", "tzone")) #cosmetics
z = unname(Map(as.POSIXct, Y$tmp, Y$tzone)) # unname is cosmetics
```

gives

```
> z 
[[1]]
[1] "2024-01-05 11:12:13 UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "2024-01-10 12:13:14 CET"

[[3]]
[1] "2024-01-15 07:08:09 EST"

> lapply(z, class)
[[1]]
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

[[2]]
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

[[3]]
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

> lapply(z, attr, "tzone")
[[1]]
[1] "UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "CET"

[[3]]
[1] "EST"
```

(Couldn't think of something more concise than `data.frame(t(list2DF(..)))` yet.)
Now you can accomplish your desired timezone conversion I suspect.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting. I don't know a lot about `lubridate::as_date()`, I prefere `lubridate::ymd_hms()`. In `lubridate::ymd_hms()` (or `parse_date_time()`) , the `tz` argument as to be of length one. You were in the right path with with `map`.

I did my example with  `with_tz(tzone="EST")` to demonstrate an alternative to UTC representation.

```
library(tidyverse)
dtf <- 
  tibble(
    x <- c("2024-01-05 11:12:13 UTC", "2024-01-10 12:13:14 CET", "2024-01-15 07:08:09 EST")
    y <- str_extract(x, "[^ ]+$")
  )

map2(dtf$x, dtf$y, \(x,y) ymd_hms(x, tz= y) %>%
       with_tz(tzone="EST")) %>% 
  list_c()
```